# Can data be accessed on a lost iPhone that was reported to "find my iPhone"

Tags: iphone

My phone was lost today, I tracked it (someone had it).

I reported it LOST with "find my iphone"and suspended my service.

Can someone activate it and use my apps, itunes, passbook, etc?

Comment: Suspending your service would only affect cellular service. They could still use wifi. However, they would need to crack your pass code in order to gain access to the device. Your other option, if you don't mind losing any data that wasn't backed up, is to erase the phone with FMI.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If you are on iOS 6, they can wipe the device and most likely establish new wireless service even in the same country as you reports it as stolen.

If you are on iOS 7, the activation lock from iCloud and Apple is a very hard thing for someone to bypass - perhaps impossible for most to use again.